# Picasso not loading splitted urls

Tags: android, string, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have string like

```
String stringUrl = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
```

Now i removed square brackets

```
 String urls = stringUrl.replace("[","").replace("]","");
```

Now i split the sting

```
String[] urlsArray = urls.split(",");
```

Now i write this code

```
for (String url : urlsArray) {
                    holder.recyclerViewHomeWorkImages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.imgButtonDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imagesList.add(new ImageHomeworkModel(url, "Name"));

                }
```

Now in **Image homework adapter i write this**

```
 ImageHomeworkModel product = imagesList.get(position);    
 Picasso.with(context).load(product.getUrls()).into(holder.imgSetData);
```

**Now the problem is picasso is loading only first url of splitted sting please help me to find solution fastly**

Comment: Did you try logging every `URL` in the for loop?

Comment: No please explain me how to do this

Comment: This line `String stringUrl = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];` is wrong because it is not a string.

Comment: Just put `Log.e("URL",url)` in the for loop and run the app and check logcat.

Comment: ya i already did this

Comment: What did you see? All `URLs` are correct? What error you are getting?

Comment: sry to not describe in question actually url contains only 1st URL from splitted string

Comment: Huh? What does that mean? Does it only have only one URL?

Comment: Ya so can you please tell me how to get lefted urls

Comment: This is wrong "`String stringUrl = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];`"

Comment: please explain me I'm not get where the problem actually is

Comment: This should be like this `String stringUrl = "[\"url1\",\"url2\", \"url3\"]";`

Comment: The complete which i am getting from firebase is this please take a look here on these response    "[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ngf-connection.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FBtech%20CSE%20I%2F917248800852_status_200b86ad9f0d43e8aab65037b1588f32.jpg?alt=media&token=47b2f7ed-3cf1-4aea-9883-0f552e24754e, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ngf-connection.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FBtech%20CSE%20I%2F917248800852_status_200b86ad9f0d43e8aab65037b1588f32.jpg?alt=media&token=47b2f7ed-3cf1-4aea-9883-0f552e24754e]"

Comment: It is `String stringUrl = "[url1,url2,ur3]"`

Comment: Don't throw links at me. I told you the real thing. Put `.toString` to the response. Then you will have the string. Then you code will work.

Comment: I tried your code it is working for me. Maybe some links are broken?

Comment: I got one more thing from logging actually url contains all urls but like URLS_OF_IMG : url1 thenURLS_OF_IMG : url2 maybe here is some problem

Comment: It is the problem. Post logcat here.

Comment: Check the logcat image it will explain you more where the problem is    https://drive.google.com/open?id=16xtlJJpOS8mTDzWqB3tyekXJIvc9suHy

Comment: `URLS_OF_IMG` is the tag of your  `Log.e` it's not in the array look at your `Log.e` statement don't worry about it.

Comment: Your links are broken! Try opening them in the browser.

Comment: They are openning correctly in browser the problem is `imagesList.add(new ImageHomeworkModel(url, "Name"));` in this url is storing onyl 1st URL and i want to store all URLS

Comment: Thank you @OhhhThatVarun for you precious time on that day. I got answerof my problem and will upload that answer by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misket that I was doing that is I was sending only last index of array 
Now, I am sending all stings one by one

```
 for (i = 0; i < urlsArray.length; i++) {
                    holder.recyclerViewHomeWorkImages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.imgButtonDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imagesList.add(new ImageHomeworkModel(urlsArray[i], fileName));
                }
```